# How to write a batch script to install ruby gem

Tags: ruby, batch-file, rubygems, yaml

I'm writing a batch script as a setup for a ruby program I'm writing. It needs to be able to

a. Make sure Ruby is installed on the user's computer (and if not point them to the ruby download page)

b. make sure the ruby "yaml" gem is installed, which is a prerequisite for it. I've tried

```
gem install yaml
```

in the batch script to no avail. How can I write a batch script that will do these two things?

Comment: You can use [bundler](http://bundler.io/) for managing gems (and respective versions).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there *is no* yaml gem.  Although it must be required in code that uses it, it is distributed as part of a Ruby installation. Try this:

```
ruby -ryaml -e"puts 'YAML found'"
```

It should work; and if you change the -r token to some nonexistent gem, you'll see an exception raised.

Comment: That's great except I have Ruby installed and am using yaml but when I run that is spits this error back at me: C:\Users\kyle>ruby yaml -ryaml -e"puts 'yaml found'"
ruby: No such file or directory -- yaml (LoadError)

Comment: You need to remove the 'yaml' after the 'ruby'.  Ruby thinks that's the filespec of a Ruby script, but in this case we don't have one.

Comment: Remember never to use tabs in a yaml file as well

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing your own script, you could use `bundler` and create a gemfile. This way people can install all the gems on any operating system.

Example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'rest-client'
#require all your gems like normal

def parse(site)
  Nokogiri::HTML(RestClient.get(site))
end
```

And for the gem file:

```
source: "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6.7.2' #<= you can specify which version
gem 'rest-client' #<= you don't have to specify a version though
```

After you've got everything set up, `cd` to the directory that has the gemfile and run `bundle install` this will install all the gems